# Java threads are concurrent or parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading

So i am pretty confused. I read in an article that version 1.7 onwards java has been 'core-aware'

Now question is if I use Thread class, will the threads be parallel or concurrent assuming that its a multi-core system and tasks are fully disjoint, and lets assume only this process is running on the system?

What was the situation before 1.7 version, does that mean java was only concurrent back then?
Also tell the same for the ForkJoinPool and ThreadPool (Executor Framework).

**Concurrent:** Not on the same instant, on same core sequentially i.e. on mercy of Thread Schedular.

**Parallel:** On the same instant on different cores e.g. 8 threads/4 cores(hyperthreaded).

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Not all programmers agree on the meaning of the terms 'parallelism' and 'concurrency'. They may define them in different ways or do not distinguish them at all. Please improve your question by: 1. giving your definitions 2. Adding a link to the article you refer to.

Comment: I think we all define "parallelism" the same way.  "Concurrency" is a bit of a sticking point because the common English usage of a similar word (concurrent) means "at the same time" but the Computer Science definition of "concurrency" allows for task to execute sequentially (i.e, *not* at the same time).

Comment: I think for a long time, Java (that is, the JVM) has used OS threads and/or OS processes for its multi-threading, so what you really get is up to the OS and its scheduler.  I don't think the JVM *prevents* you from scheduling threads in parallel, but depending on various factors the threads may or may not literally execute in parallel.  I think this has been true for a long time (well before Java 1.5) but things got more definite by the 1.5 release and any otherwise eligible task from that point should be eligible for parallelism if the OS permits it.

Comment: I also have a minor quibble: hardware can be parallel as well, starting around the Pentium 5 in 1990 for common hardware.  A single process with a single thread could still execute in parallel, since those cores had two instruction pipelines which could execute two machine instructions at the same instant.  But I realize this is getting far afield of what you were actually talking about.

Comment: @markspace Thanks for that knowledge though, any new knowledge is appreciated.. thanks for the edit too

Comment: Maybe this article: https://qr.ae/pruIFr

Comment: That article is full of inaccuracies.  For instance the "core-awareness" that he is apparently talking about has always been a feature of Java since Java 1.3 when "green threads" were replaces with "native threads".

Comment: Chetan: It is a well known fact that a lot of the articles that one reads on the internet are either incorrect or just someone's (ill-informed) opinion.  Before asking an SO question like this, it is important that you do some *independent* research (e.g. finding and reading reputable academic sources, or even just Wikipedia) ... rather than (in effect) asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel *is* concurrent. "Concurrent" means that the effective order in which events from two or more different threads happen is undefined (not counting events like unlocking a mutex that are specifically intended to coordinate the threads.) "Parallel" means, that the threads are using more CPU resources than a single CPU core is able to provide. Threads can't run in parallel without also running concurrently.

> What was the situation before 1.7 version

I don't remember what changed with 1.7, but I was using Java from its earliest days, and the language always promised that threads would run concurrently. Whether or not they also were able to run in parallel was outside of the scope of the language spec. It depended on what hardware you were running on, what operating system and version, what JVM and version, etc.

Comment: However, "concurrency" is a different word than the ones you use above.  And it's official definition allows tasks to execute sequentially.  That's how you can have "concurrency" in languages with a global interpreter lock that prevents any possibility of parallelism.

Comment: @markspace, Nothing that I said rules out the possibility that in some execution, two "concurrent" threads actually run one after the other. And nothing that I said rules out the possibility of having concurrent threads in a certain language that has a "Global Interpreter Lock."

Comment: There is an academic definition of the work "concurrency" which I bet a large percentage of thread programmers would disagree with.  It is more complicated because the word "concurrent" in the post is a different word with a specific dictionary definition.  I would say "concurrency theory" is what you are describing.  To me concurrency is a synonym of concurrence and I've been a thread programmer for 30 years and learned it before they taught it (which is probably the problem).

Comment: How about this definition then? Two function activations are "concurrent" during any interval of time when both of them have been started, but neither one of them has finished. It's a little bit broader because _recursive_ calls from the same thread count as "concurrent" by that definition, but if we stipulate that the two calls happen in different threads, then in practice, it implies the kind of "concurrency" that I described above.

Comment: Here's a MIT reading with some different context. 
 "Concurrency means multiple computations are happening at the same time." https://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa14/classes/17-concurrency/

Comment: For me two function activations are "concurrent" if they are executing simultaneously but again I'm an old thread programmer.

Comment: @Gray, But it's the ambiguity in "_executing_ simultaneously" that drives the OP to ask the question. If function `f` calls function `g` in a single thread, can we say that the two functions "execute simultaneously?" (Sounds dubious to me!) If `f` and `g` are called by different threads on a single-CPU machine, can we say that they may "execute simultaneously?" (More than one newbie here has struggled to understand that exact question). IMO, the way to disambiguate is to exorcize the word "simultaneous" from any definition of concurrency, and only use it when talking about "parallelism."

Comment: Agreed @SolomonSlow.  Sounds confusing to me as well.  I would certainly say that the latter is simultaneous given that the word means "done at the same time".  The former is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> So i am pretty confused. I read in an article that version 1.7 onwards java has been 'core-aware'

I think the context matters.  Maybe you are talking about [this Quora post](https://qr.ae/pruIFr)?  To quote:

> Ever since Java 7, the JVM has been core-aware and able to access cores within a CPU. If the host has two CPUs with two cores each, then it can create four threads and dispatch them to each of the four cores.

This is not talking about the differences between concurrency theory or parallelism but rather about how the JVM interfaces with the OS and the hardware to provide thread services to the application.

> What was the situation before 1.7 version, does that mean java was only concurrent back then?

Java threads have been available for some time before 1.7.  Most of the concurrency stuff was greatly improved in 1.5.  Again, the post seems specifically about CPUs verses cores.  Applications before 1.7 could use multiple cores to run in parallel.

> Now question is if I use Thread class, will the threads be parallel or concurrent assuming that its a multi-core system and tasks are fully disjoint, and lets assume only this process is running on the system?

So this part of the question seems to be addressing the academic terms "parallel" and "concurrent".  @SolomonSlow sounds like they have more academic instruction around this.  I've been programming threads for 30+ years starting when they were non-preemptive – back when reentrance was more about recursion than threads.

To me "concurrent" means in parallel – running concurrency on a single piece of hardware put on different cores (physical or virtual).  I understand that this [wikipedia page on Concurrency (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) disagrees with my definition.

I also understand that a threaded program may run serially depending on many factors including the application itself, the OS, the load on the server running it, etc. and there is a lot of theory behind all this.

> Concurrent: Not on the same instant, on same core sequentially i.e. on mercy of Thread Schedular.

This definition I disagree with.  The wikipedia page talks about the fact that 2 concurrent units can run in parallel or out of order which could mean sequentially, but it's not part of the definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the actual change that the "article" was referring to happened in Java 1.3 when the "green thread" implementation<sup>1</sup> was replaced with "native" threads.  (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_thread)

---

However, your distinction between Concurrent vs Parallel does not match Oracle / Sun's definitions; see [Sun's Multithreaded Programming Guide: Defining Multithreading Terms](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032b/index.html).

> "Parallelism: A condition that arises when at least two threads are executing simultaneously."
>
> "Concurrency: A condition that exists when at least two threads are making progress. **A more generalized form of parallelism** that can include time-slicing as a form of virtual parallelism.".

This also aligns with what the [Wikipedia page on Concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) says.

> "In computer science, concurrency is the ability of different parts or units of a program, algorithm, or problem to be executed out-of-order or in partial order, without affecting the outcome. **This allows for parallel execution of the concurrent units, which can significantly improve overall speed of the execution in multi-processor and multi-core systems.**"

---

If you could give us a citation for the source(s) of your definitions of "Concurrent" and "Parallel", it would help us to understand whether there is a genuine dispute about the terminology ... or ... you are simply misinformed.

---

<sup>1 - Interesting fact: they were called "green threads" because the Sun team that developed the first Java release was called the "Green Team".  Source: ["Java Technology: The early years"](https://web.archive.org/web/20080530073139/http://java.sun.com/features/1998/05/birthday.html) by Jon Byous, April 2003.</sup>